# Using Libcurl as a Win32 DLL C++

Tags: c++, dll, libcurl

I want to create a win32 DLL what use libcurl in C++. I can run curl init and escape but I can't perform CURLOPT_URL. This is my code:

```
EXPORT_VBNET char *MyExported( char *a, char *b){  
      const char* success = "executed!";
      const char* failed = "error!";
      char * result;
      result = new char[strlen(failed) + 1];
      strcpy(result, failed);
      CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
      if(curl) {
              curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1/"); // ERROR Debug Assertion Failed!
              curl_easy_perform(curl);
              result = new char[strlen(success) + 1];
              strcpy(result, success);
       }
       return result;}
```

My code can be compiled, but when I call the dll I get an error *"Debug Assertion Failed!"*. So what should I do to fix my code, I mean what's wrong with this?

I would be grateful if anyone answered. Because I've spent a lot of time to googling this problem. :)

Comment: Not related to your crash, but you have two memory leaks after calling `curl_easy_perform()`. You are not calling `delete[] result` before reallocating `result`, and you are not calling `curl_easy_cleanup()`. You are also not checking if `curl_easy_perform()` succeeds before you return the `success` reply to the caller. Your `EXPORT_VBNET` also implies that `VB.NET` is the caller. It will not be able to free the returned `result` string, unless your DLL exports another function that calls `delete[]` on VB.NET's behalf.

Comment: Are you sure the debug assert is on `curl_easy_setopt()` and not on somewhere else?  What does the assert's error message actually say when you debug the code?

Comment: yes,... maybe? 
it says:
program: h:\blahblah,..\project1.exe
file: f:\dd\cvtools\crt\self_x86\src\dbgheap.c
line:1322

expression:_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

for information ... blah..

(press rety ro debug the application)

Comment: @RemyLebeau well i can call curl_easy_cleanup() so I think it's not the problem. I cant even pass this code
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1/"); 
curl_easy_perform(curl);

Comment: Are you using Visual C++? Looks like it's because of different run-time library. Your compiled curl dll and your app should have the same type of run-time library. You can check the run-time library: Project properties->C/C++->Code Generation and on the right pane, you should see Run time library

Comment: You have not called ::curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT) before invoking curl_easy_init. That should be the reason

Comment: @Asesh yes, Visual C++ 2010. the caller app using vb6. already add curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT); before curl_easy but still getting error my runtime library /MDd, /MD will resulting appCrash, /MT resulting a lot error between MSVCRT.lib and LIBCMT.lib(can't compiled).

Comment: You should post the debug assertion error too

Comment: @Asesh here:
program: h:\blahblah,..\project1.exe
file: f:\dd\cvtools\crt\self_x86\src\dbgheap.c
line:1322
expression:_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)
for information ... blah.. 
(press rety ro debug the application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes @Asesh is right, but Curl_global_init has nothing to do with the problem in my code. The problem is at my run-time library and after seeing this link

https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2011-10/0085.html. I've fixed my problem.

### I need to replace

*C:\libcurl\builds\libcurl-vc10-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl*

to

*C:\libcurl\builds\libcurl-vc10-x86-debug-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl*
(include & Lib directory)

*Libcurl_a.lib* to *libcurl_a_debug.lib.*

With run-time library /MDd.

**Finally :).**

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT) from inside the Win32 DLL rather than from the VB.NET layer. Also, encapsulate all the libcurl api calls like the curl_easy_cleanup(), etc inside the Win32 DLL itself. From API design perspective you may export separate methods for initialization, cleanup, etc to the VB.NET layer.

Comment: I have tried With or without curl_global_init from this code https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html Of course without using fprintf and I have also edited the return so it can run win32dll. Just like my code above. But still has not worked. Maybe you want to give an example?